# Building a gnu auto tools c/c++ project with maven

Tags: c++, c, maven, autotools

I would like to know if it is possible to build a gnu auto tools based C/C++ project with maven. The build process involves running the "configure" script with configure options and then executing a "make" command on the Makefile generated as a result of the configure step.

Apparently, it seems like the configure script could be invoked using Maven "exec" plugin and the make file can be executed with "exec" or "antrun" plugin. However this approach seems to be somewhat crude in nature.

It would be really great if people can share their experiences or possible 
ways for achieving the above mentioned goal.

Thanks...
Bunny

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using maven2 to build autotools-based C/C++ package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190996/using-maven2-to-build-autotools-based-c-c-package)

Comment: The links mentioned there for make-maven-plugin or cbuild parent don't work anymore. Even google searches for these plugins don't yield anything.

Comment: Adding that to question will be helpful then

Comment: There are projects which uses maven-exec-plugin for this, eg https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video

Comment: @rkosegi Looks promising.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are going the right way based on C/C++ projects to be built with Maven. If you really like to take a look here: http://maven-nar.github.io/